# Find exact substring from line using batch script

Tags: batch-file

Now I'm trying to write a script which will  get exact string from the line. For example:

```
echo asdf C:\ | findstr /C:"C:\\" 1>nul 
if errorlevel 1 ( echo not found ) else ( echo found )
```

In above script, i just wanna make sure that C:\ drive exist in echo command. But when i add some text to echo command like this:

```
echo asdf C:\sdfdf | findstr /C:"C:\\" 1>nul
if errorlevel 1 ( echo not found ) else ( echo found )
```

It still tell me C:\ exist. I just want to find exact string in line. Can someone suggest me something?

Thanks in advanced!

Sorry for my bad code and English!

**Update**:

Sorry guys,

Let me explain more about my idea. I was working on Windows Server migration. From old server I have to migrate shared folder which doesn't contains Default Share or Remote Admin location to new server. I tried code a batch script like below to list all shared folder which i need to migrate and next time i will modify it to automatically using xcopy to copy it to the new server. But I'm stucking with getting exact string from output to list exact shared folder which i need. Here is my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Get list shared folder
echo:
echo ^<=================Get list shared folder================^>
for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%i in ('"wmic share get name,path"') do (
    for /F "tokens=1" %%s in ('echo %%i') do (
    REM Check content doesn't contains $ special character, ECHO text
        echo %%s | findstr /C:"$" 1>nul
        REM if not contains $
        if errorlevel 1 (
        REM if not contains ECHO text
            echo %%s | findstr /C:"ECHO" 1>nul
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo %%i
                echo %%i | findstr /C:"C:\\" 1>nul
                if errorlevel 1 (
                    echo %%i
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Thank you guys all very much. Can everybody suggest me how to find exact drive like D:\, C:..etc. to exclude it from the result?

Thanks in advanced!

P/s: Sorry for my bad code and poor English.

Comment: You are using "C:\\" to findstr, then it will always tell you C:\ exists. If you findstr "C:\\sdfdf" then it will tell C:\sdfdf exists.

Comment: C:\ does exist within `asdf C:\sdfdf` so explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should also realise that `echo asdf C:\ | findstr` has a space after the backslash.  That can be a trap when you aren't aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (ugly) regex with `findstr` to return lines that contain `C:\` without a suffix:

```
findstr /i "c:\\[^;0-9a-zA-z-~\-=+']"
```

The regex excludes lines with any (legal) character appended to `c:\`.

The `/i` allows for either `C:\` or `c:\`.

This will prevent matches like `C:\sdfdf`. It won't prevent prefix characters, e.g. `2c:\`. However, you can probably glean from the above regex how to deal with that.

Comment: `findstr /r /i "c:\\$"` <-- this should also work to find c:\ with nothing following it.

Comment: `c:\\$` will only match if "c:\" is at the end of the line. For example, "c:\   <spaces and/or stuff>" doesn't match. That said, it's not entirely clear what the exact criteria is.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it (not sure), the problem is determine if the string `c:\` appears inside a line without any prefix/suffix. This should do the trick

```
findstr /i /r /c:" c:\\ " /c:" c:\\$" /c:"^c:\\ " /c:"^c:\\$"
```

It only handles all the needed cases:

```
space         String  space
space         String  EndOfString
StartOfString String  space
StartOfString String  EndOfString
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WMIC that way gives you output that is difficult to parse.  It's Unicode and it has trailing spaces.

Try this, and then parse the resulting file b.tmp and you can further filter the result by `Name=` or `Path=`

```
wmic share get name,path /value >a.tmp
type a.tmp |find "=" >b.tmp
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really useful. But can you tell me how to filter the result like your comment? I don't have much experience in Batch script. It's quite hard, not flexible and powerful like Bash Shell which i used before.

Comment: change `find "="` to `find "Path="`

Comment: Thanks but if I change like that, for ex in case the "Name=" contains the string with some spaces like "Name=abc xyz" then it just show in echo is "Name=abc". Do you know how to use regex in find command?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If you use `find` as shown, it will give you the entire line.  If you use a `for /f "delims="` in a loop then it will also give you the entire line. I do use regexp with findstr, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me give it a try.